# JavaScript not working locally but works on fiddle

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to prevent users entering the wrong date.I have found Momemnt.js for handling dates and it works on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/6MEG6/).

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src='http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.min.js'>



    $(document).ready(function() {

       function CheckForPastDate(sender, args) {

    selectedDate = sender._selectedDate;
    var todayDate = new Date();
    if (selectedDate.getTime() < todayDate.getTime()) {
        sender.selectedDate = todayDate;
        sender._textbox.value = moment(selectedDate).format(sender._format);
        alert("Wrong date!");
       }
   }

 CheckForPastDate({
 _textbox: document.getElementById('<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>'),
 _selectedDate: new Date(2013, 5, 3),
 _format: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'
  });



});






     </script>
     </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">   
       </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckForPastDate">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
   </html>
```

So I have downloaded moment.js using nuget but it doesn't work anyway. I don't get any exceptions but I dont get wrong date messages either .

Comment: possible duplicate of [my jquery fiddle isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556509/my-jquery-fiddle-isnt-working)

Comment: where do you call the javascript function outside of javascript? it won't run inside the script tags like that

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you're referencing the `moments.js` library somewhere in your page before using it, If you put it like this (in that order) in your code, by the time the Javascript will be executed, the controls don't exist yet on the page. you should put the javascript below the HTML/ASPX code, or better, execute your javascript when document is ready.

That's the difference with the JSFiddle : the javascript code is put after the HTML code in the rendering.

You should also be aware that different things in .NET can cause the client ID of your controls to change. I mean, if you put this into a panel for example, the resulting ID of your textbox once rendered in HTML will most probably (although you can now set this off if I'm not mistaken) be different than the one you specified in the javascript. It will include the id of all containers, ie the ID of the parent panel.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`<script src = 'http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.min.js' />`

You must `include` the `moment` library to call the `moment()` function.

It works in the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/6MEG6/)** because it is included under *External Resources.*

Comment: I have editted my code .But I think I messed it  up everything .Because I couldnt make it run again